# How to retrieve certain tables from database using PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table with these columns:

```
+------------------------------------------------------+
| ad_id | ad_title | active |   placed_on   | duration | 
+------------------------------------------------------+
|     1 | First    |      1 |  2010-19-10   |      365 |
+------------------------------------------------------+
|     2 | Second   |      1 |  2011-18-10   |      365 |
+------------------------------------------------------+
```

It's a table for listings that expire in 365 days from day it's `placed_on` and I wanted to create a PHP + SQL statement that would show listings that expire this month (e.g. first ad which was placed last year and expires today). How can I do math on those dates, like this `2010-19-10 + 365`? and show the ones that expire this month. My brain froze after getting to:

```
mysql_query("SELECT `ad_id`, `ad_title`, `active` FROM `listings` WHERE `placed_on` = ``;
```

Is it even possible, if yes, please advise me. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`adddate`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_adddate) for your date arithmetic:

```
select ad_id, ad_title, active
from listings
where adddate(placed_on, concat(duration, ' days')) between '2011-10-01' and '2011-10-31'
```

Presumably you can supply the first and last days of the month from your PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Well if this is not your table and you can't make placed_on into something a little nicer to work with, you can generate your offset date on the front end and pass that to:

```
STRCMP()
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html#function_strcmp

```
WHERE STRCMP(placed_on,'2010-19-10') = 1 ORDER BY placed_on
```

will give you everything newer than 2010-19-10.